# Toggle button background color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can some one help me with this please http://jsfiddle.net/ukkj7dth/5/

it works perfectly on toggling buttons but i don't why it's working on jsfiddle and not working in my page. do i need some js file?

```
<div class="button">button 1</div>
<div class="button">button 2</div>
<div class="button">button 3</div>
<div class="button">button 4</div>
<div class="button">button 5</div>
<div class="button">button 6</div>
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery installed and included in your page?

Comment: Could you please provide a link or something to your page so we can see the original code?

Comment: i have this on header but not working <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/264659524/Files/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to fire the code on `DOM ready` like so:

```
$(function() { //<<<<----
    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('myClass').siblings().removeClass('myClass');
    });
}); //<<<<----
```

It works in jsfiddle because you're firing the code on `window load` ... see `onLoad` in dropdown. If you set jsfiddle to `no wrap in <head>` it'll stop working -- which would be close to what you might have in your application.

[**Does Not Work**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ukkj7dth/6/)

[**Works**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ukkj7dth/7/)

Comment: i don't get it sir but as you see in that link i provided of left side in "Frameworks & Extensions" area, there's something called "jQuery 1.11.0" and when i change it, the code doesn't work. is that some file that i need to have?

Comment: Can you provide all the relevant code you have on your page. Forget about jsfiddle.

Comment: oh i just noticed if i put my js code between <body> and </body> then it willl work. but why i can't put it in head or in js file?

Comment: That's probably because your JS is now below the .button element. If you put it above it won't work.

Comment: <html>
<head>

<style>
.button{border:1px solid #444;background:green;float:left;margin:3px;padding:3px;}
.myClass{background:yellow;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/264659524/Files/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="button">button 1</div>
<div class="button">button 2</div>

<script>
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('myClass').siblings().removeClass('myClass');
})
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: If you copy and paste the code I provided in my answer into the <head> section it should work fine.  You don't need to put your JS in the body.

Comment: thanks a lot master it worked perfectly now but i need that "jquery-1.9.0.min.js" file too right?

Comment: and 1 more thing, what if i wanted the text color must change on click instead of that div is background? can you help me with my code or create new one in some jsfiddle link